# HTML5: iOS screen scrolls up when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, css, html, keyboard, scroll

Say you've got a Xcode app with embedded web view exposing a simple HTML5 page.
This page has a title and an input tag and a nav top bar (position: fixed; top:0;).

When the user tap in it the first time, the whole screen scrolls up to enable the keyboard appears while maintaining the input tag visible, when I tap the enter button.

The issue I face is that my HTML is not restored identically (I mean, it scrolls down back, but my top bar is shifted about 10 pixels below the top edge of the screen.

But when I tap the keyboard hide button, the scrolls restore my initial view, with no issue.

Anyone experienced the issue before? Any clue of what going on or a way to work around this?

Ps: issue is present on iOS 7 (7.1.2). I didn't tested on iOS 8 as my app must support iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with adding an explicit keyboard withdrawing by applying blur() the the input as follows:

```
<input ng-change="$(this).blur()">
```

This immediately makes the keyboard disappearing, while the hw initial scrolling is reversed.